# Using pkg-config with autotools

Tags: makefile, autotools, automake

I'm learning about the autotools and made it through a hello world scenario and now wanted to try wrapping up some cppunit tests into a package and build it using the autotools.  In order to build the package, cppunit would have to be installed on the system.  What's the best way to check for this during the ./configure portion of the build.

I looked into [`AC_CHECK_LIB`](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.70/html_node/Libraries.html) and then ran across some info about using pkg-config.  How would I use pkg-config in the autotools realm to check for the existence of cppunit on the build system & then add the include & link lines.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Steve

Comment: Be wary of pkg-config.  Many people consider it to be fundamentally broken.

Comment: @WilliamPursell can you elaborate? Who are these people, and why do they consider pkg-config broken? (There are many people who think pkg-config works well...)

Comment: @DanC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful/10229811#10229811

Answer (score 14, accepted):

pkg-config comes with its own set of Autoconf macros such as `PKG_CHECK_EXIST` and `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`.  They are documented in the pkg-config man page.

cppunit also comes with its own Autoconf macro `AM_PATH_CPPUNIT` in the `cppunit.m4` file.  So that's probably the best place to start.