# Specifying Library paths in Makefile

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, autoconf, automake

I am using autoconf and automake for a C++ project, and I expect that g++ will be smart enough to look at `/usr/include/<library-name>` when my source code already have

```
#include <libxml/xpath.h>
#include <libxml/xpathInternals.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <libxml/tree.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
```

When I just run `./configure && make` , I get this error

```
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..   -Wall -O2   -g -O2 -MT azurefs.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/azurefs.Tpo -c -o azurefs.o azurefs.cpp
azurefs.cpp:33:26: fatal error: libxml/xpath.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated
```

I have to include the library path using `CCXXFLAGS` this way

```
$ CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 ./configure && make
```

Is there a better way to write my code, Makefile or autoconf files so that g++ will look for the libraries correctly in `/usr/include/<library-name>`  ?

Comment: There is a better way :  `./configure CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 && make`.  (assuming you are using a version of autoconf that is not ancient)

Answer (score 2):

In my Makefile.am I have the following line to add g++ arguments:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/src/include/ --std=c++0x
```

I think that you need something like that:

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = `pkg-config --cflags libxml-2.0`
```

So you also don't need to worry where the includes are located on another system.

Comment: I used CXXFLAGS which seemed to work. What is the prefix AM_ for?

For example: CXXFLAGS=-I/usr/include/libxml2 ./configure

Comment: I don't know if this is a good idea. If I want to build your application, I need to know that I have to set CXXFLAGS that way.

AM_CPPFLAGS is a variable inside Makefile.am. If you set it there, no one has to bother in the future.

Comment: No!  No!  No!  If you are going to use `pkg-config`, then use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, but do not do that.  (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful).  If the user installs a library in a non-standard location, it is the user's responsibility to tell the compiler, and the user should set `CPPFLAGS` at configure time.  It is not the package maintainer's responsibility to do basic system admin work for the user.

Comment: These are not arguments for `g++`.  These are arguments for the preprocessor.  Keep in mind that the user may be using any compiler and any preprocessor, and you must not assume `g++`, or `gcc`, or `cpp`, or any tool with which you are familiar.