# PKG_CHECK_MODULES vs AC_CHECK_LIB for checking availability of libraries

Tags: autotools, autoconf, pkg-config

I am using autotools for a project. I wanted to understand the **best practice** when it comes to checking for the existence of libraries?

I tried using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`, but unfortunately many of the libraries I am using don't show up in `pkg-config --list-all` (even after running ldconfig).

The alternative is to use `AC_CHECK_LIB`, but that requiress me to specify an example function from each library that I need to test for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever a third party software supports pkg-config, use it. If the third party software has no pkg-config support, you have to write your own check.

Unless Autoconf already provides a test or you can copy a test from an other open source project.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I finally decided to use AC_CHECK_LIB for those libraries alone.

Answer (score 2):

I'll have to disagree with the accepted answer.  (See [PKG_CHECK_MODULES considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful))  PKG_CHECK_MODULES was popular for a time many years ago, but was never considered good practice by a majority of developers on the autoconf mailing lists.  The autotools are not a package management system, and PKG_CHECK_MODULES seems to be an attempt to shoe-horn package management functionality in.  If a package uses PKG_CHECK_MODULES, the configure script must still invoke AC_CHECK_LIB to validate the information returned by pkg-config or risk a build failure.  Further, if a user invokes `configure` with LDFLAGS=-l/p/a/t/h/, they should reliably expect the build to use `/p/a/t/h/liboo.so` rather than using some other location, but PKG_CHECK_MODULES requires that the user either override PKG_CONFIG_PATH or otherwise alter the response from pkg-config in order to override a library search path.

Comment: Fair enough. Is the right solution then to always use AC_CHECK_LIB? It doesn't work very well for C++ functions though (http://nerdland.net/2009/07/detecting-c-libraries-with-autotools/). Besides, pkg-config --libs (when it does work) gives you secondary library dependencies as well.