# autoconf: Set AC_CHECK_LIB compiler flags

Tags: c++, autotools, autoconf, automake

I am trying to set up my project to use the autotools build system for distribution. However, I am having a problem when it comes to including a few extra libraries.

My code depends on a few libraries:

- One I wrote (I'll call libfoo)
- One that is third party (I'll call libbar)
- Eigen3 (which is just header files)

These are all already compiled and installed in my $HOME directory. I do not need to build them as part of this project.

The flags I need are

```
-std=c++11 (Got this taken care of)
```

and

```
-I/path/to/include/libfoo (or libbar, or Eigen3)
```

and

```
-L/path/to/lib/ (Where libfoo and libbar reside)
```

and

```
-lfoo
```

to compile and link against libfoo and libbar

The problem is that I want to set up checks for the presence of libfoo and libbar and their headers (I have a check for Eigen3 set up already). The issue is that macros like AC_CHECK_HEADERS and AC_CHECK_LIB don't seem to want to include the required CPPFLAGS or LDFLAGS, no matter how I try to define them, so the configuration step fails.

```
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([libfoo/foo.h], , [echo "Did not find libfoo headers"; exit -1])
AC_LANG_POP([C++])
```

Reading config.log shows that configure is trying to compile against the header using

```
g++ -std=c++11 (other flags...)
```

but is failing due to the missing flags above (The error is "Cannot find Eigen3/dense", or similar, indicating the missing -I flag)

I'm a newbie to autotools, so I may be missing something obvious, but I've read through a good amount of help and manuals and have so far failed to figure out what I need to do to set this up.

Related: I want the user to be able to manually specify the location of libfoo and libbar via --with-libfoo-include (etc) if needed, so I also need to be able to specify where configure detects these libraries. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone who stumbled across this wondering the same thing, I found my answer by looking at the autotools files from another open source project:

First off, to add the --with-x-include=option flag, you use

```
AC_ARG_WITH
```

Second, the rough procedure for doing this check involved first checking if the header file you want even exists where you said it should be using

```
AC_CHECK_FILE
```

then I save the old CPPFLAGS, and then add the required include's. I could then check the header using

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER
```

and finally, using the on-success argument to that macro, I set a variable that I later test. If true, I define the variable LIBFOO_INC using the user specified include path.

Finally, I also found the macro AX_CXX_CHECK_LIB, which allows for library checking in C++ libraries. It is available in the [ac-archive](http://ac-archive.sourceforge.net/guidod/ax_cxx_check_lib.html)

As a note, in my case I needed to define some of these flags for both CPPFLAGS and CXXFLAGS, so this involved manually setting them in some places. It may not always affect people, but it's a potential gotcha.

Answer (score 4):

All you need to do are:

For

> -std=c++11 (Got this taken care of)

is good to use [ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.m4](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html)
To use it, you need to download it from the above link and set it in **$(project_top)/m4/**
Next, you write like below in **configure.ac**:

```
AX_CXX_COMPILE_STDCXX_11([noext], [mandatory])
```

And exec, you can check it's possible or not to use C++11 feature in the platform

```
$ autoreconf -vi -I m4
$ ./configure
```

and

> -I/path/to/include/libfoo (or libbar, or Eigen3)
>   -L/path/to/lib/ (Where libfoo and libbar reside)
>   -lfoo

This is difficult to explain simply,

1. The library provides **.pc** file
   You should use **PKG_CHECK_MODULES** macro
   You should refer [Guide to pkg-config](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html) and [The PKG_CHECK_MODULES Macro](https://autotools.io/pkgconfig/pkg_check_modules.html)
   This would help to receive include path and library path.
2. The library provides **foo-config** shell
   For example, libcurl provides **curl-config**, libxml2 provides **xml2-config**. So, we can get include/lib path using this shell.

   ```
   CURL_LIBS=`$CURLCONFIG --libs`  
   CURL_CFLAGS=`$CURLCONFIG --cflags`
   ```
3. The library written in C and provides nothing
   You should use **AC_CHECK_HEADER/AC_CHECK_LIB**
   You can refer about it [AC_CHECK_HEADER](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.61/html_node/Generic-Headers.html) , [AC_CHECK_LIB](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Libraries.html)
4. The library written in C++ and provides nothing
   Use **AC_TRY_LINK/AC_LANG_PUSH**, **AC_LANG_POP** like below...

   ```
   AC_MSG_CHECKING([for some_cpp_lib])
   AC_LANG_PUSH(C++)
   SAVE_LIBS="$LIBS"
   LIBS="$LIBS -lsome_cpp_lib"
   AC_TRY_LINK([#include <some_cpp_lib.hpp>], 
           [SomeCppLib object;],
           has_some_cpp_lib=1,
           has_some_cpp_lib=0)
   AC_LANG_POP(C++)
   if test $has_some_cpp_lib = 0; then
     AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
   else
     AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
   fi
   ```

Comment: It is not obvious that this will supplement the `LDFLAGS` so that the libraries in out of the way places will be made available via `-L` *path* arguments to the linker.  Does this happen auto-magically when the library's presence is confirmed with a `AC_CHECK_LIB` (or the recommended, better `AC_SEARCH_LIBS`)? OTOH It is probably not right to try to specify a library location in a `configure.ac` entry anyhow as it more properly belongs as an `LDFLAGS="-L/p/a/t/h"` argument to `configure` to be used by the end-user/compiler...

Comment: **Thank you for #4.** For some reason, the automake devs have not seen fit to include C++ headers when `AC_SEARCH_LIBS` is testing a C++ file. (Or, if they have, they've done a good job of hiding it in the manual, so I'd appreciate the pointer.) It took me an hour of pulling my hair out before I realized it was a C++ thing (and I figured that out only because it worked fine with `gmp`, but not with `gmpxx`). Writing up an m4 script using this as a guide took less than 5 minutes. Wow.

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to get compiler and linker flags right, is to use `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` which uses `pkg-config` behind the scenes to let the libraries provide the correct flags.

```
 PKG_CHECK_MODULES([FOO], [foo >= 3])
```

though your [mileage may vary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946)...