# cmake: Enable features based on the result of multiple find_package() calls

Tags: build, cmake

I have a project that contains a visual debugger that I want to build only if a group of packages were found. I don't want to force a user that just want to build the base application to install all the debugger dependencies, so I don't mark then as REQUIRED when running find_package().

Right now my build looks like this:

> ./CMakeList

```
find_package(gazebo)
find_package(OpenGL)
find_package(GLUT)

add_subdirectory(debugger)
```

> ./debugger/CMakeList

```
if(NOT gazebo_FOUND OR NOT OpenGL_FOUND OR NOT GLUT_FOUND)
    return()
endif()
```

This works just fine, but as the list of dependencies for the debugger grows, using this **if** to enable/disable the debugger build looks clumsy.

Is there a better alternative to enable the build of this sub-directory base on the result of find_package()?

The debugger is not the only thing in my project that I enable/disable this way, so I need a generic solution for enabling features based on the packages found.

Comment: Have you considered using [`FindPkgConfig`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) module to combine the search for packages into a single call/result variable? Something like `pkg_check_modules(DebuggerDeps gazebo gl glu)`? Some more information on the pros/cons can be found e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful).

Comment: Or use [`CMakeDependentOption`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeDependentOption.html) module with something like `CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION(BUILD_DEBUGGER "Build debugger" ON "gazebo_FOUND;OpenGL_FOUND;GLUT_FOUND" OFF)`. But I would - if the project is huge - maybe just write my own `my_target_link_libraries()` function which includes the necessary `if (TARGET ...)` dependency checks and removes the main target from `all`/default build if it fails.

Answer (score 1):

CMake has **no** already-made a macro or a function to check list of variables at once.

But it is not a difficult to write a function which do that. E.g.:

```
# Usage: feature_check(FEATURE_VAR REQUIRED_VAR [REQUIRED_VAR2 ...])
#
# Set FEATURE_VAR to TRUE if all required vars are TRUE,
# Otherwise set FEATURE_VAR to FALSE.
function(feature_check FEATURE_VAR REQUIRED_VAR)
    foreach(var ${REQUIRED_VAR} ${ARGN})
        if(NOT ${var})
            set(${FEATURE_VAR} "FALSE" PARENT_SCOPE)
            return()
        endif(NOT ${var})
    endforeach(var ${REQUIRED_VAR} ${ARGN})
    set(${FEATURE_VAR} "TRUE" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(feature_check FEATURE_VAR REQUIRED_VAR)
```

So, in you case you may use

```
# In CMakeList.txt, after find_package()
feature_check(USE_DEBUGGER gazebo_FOUND OpenGL_FOUND GLUT_FOUND)

# In debugger/CMakeList.txt
if(NOT USE_DEBUGGER)
    return()
endif(NOT USE_DEBUGGER)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Turning my comments into an answer**

I see three alternatives:

1. Using [`FindPkgConfig`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html) module to combine the search for packages into a single call/result variable? Something like:

   ```
   pkg_check_modules(DEBUGGER_DEPS gazebo gl glu)
   ```

   would - on platforms with `pkg-config` - also make the `find_package()` calls obsolete by using the results of the above call:

   ```
   target_compile_options(debugger PUBLIC ${DEBUGGER_DEPS_CFLAGS})
   target_link_libraries(debugger PUBLIC ${DEBUGGER_DEPS_LDFLAGS})
   ```
2. Using [`CMakeDependentOption`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CMakeDependentOption.html) module to combine the boolean values into a single option to check with something like

   ```
   CMAKE_DEPENDENT_OPTION(
        BUILD_DEBUGGER "Build debugger" ON
                       "gazebo_FOUND;OpenGL_FOUND;GLUT_FOUND" OFF
   )
   ```
3. Or - if the project is huge - maybe just write my own `my_target_link_libraries()` function which includes the necessary `if (TARGET ...)` dependency checks and removes the main target from all/default build if it fails:

   ```
   function(my_target_link_libraries _target)
       foreach(_dep IN ITEMS ${ARGN})
           if (TARGET _dep)
               target_link_libraries(${_target} ${_dep})
           else()
               message(STATUS "No target '${_dep}' found. Disabling '${_target}' build")
               set_target_properties(${_target} PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_DEFAULT_BUILD 1)
           endif()
       endforach()
   endfunction()

   my_target_link_libraries(debugger GLUT::GLUT ...)
   ```