# proper way to link a library with autotools

Tags: autotools, autoconf, automake, pkg-config

I need to link libmagic to my project which is built with autotools.

my current solution is: `LIBS+="-lmagic"` in `configure.ac`

but I think that a more proper way to achieve this would be using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro in `configure.ac` and `LDADD = @MAGIC_LIBS@` in Makefile.am, unfortunately this isn't working.

here is what i'm getting from `./configure`

```
configure: error: Package requirements (magic) were not met:

No package 'magic' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

I think this has something to do with the absence of libmagic in pkg-config,
any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think that a more proper way to achieve this would be using `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` macro in `configure.ac` [...]

Only if you actually have a pkg-config data file for libmagic, and even then [there is some controversy around `PKG_CHECK_MODULES`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220946/pkg-check-modules-considered-harmful).  As far as I can determine, [the implementation you are probably using](https://www.darwinsys.com/file/) does not provide a pkg-config file.  You could write your own, of course, but that would defeat the purpose.

If you're going to rely on the header and library being installed in one of the standard locations -- which is conventional and eminently reasonable -- then a more idiomatic way to configure the build would be to have `configure` test for their presence.  For example,

```
AC_CHECK_HEADER([magic.h], [], [
  AC_MSG_ERROR([required header magic.h not found])
])
AC_SEARCH_LIBS([magic_open], [magic], [], [
  AC_MSG_ERROR([required library libmagic not found])
])
```

Note that `AC_SEARCH_LIBS()` will automatically prepend `-lmagic` to `LIBS` if it is found.

You could get fancier by providing `configure` options by which a user could specify alternative locations for the header and library, but that doesn't seem to be what you're looking for, and it seems like it would be overkill for libmagic.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pkgconfig file for libmagic. If there is no magic.pc in your PKG_CONFIG_PATH, you have to write a custom autoconf macro to set MAGIC_LIBS.